# The minimum value of a energy integral

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde, potential-theory

Let $D \subset {\mathbb{R}^3}$ a simple connected open domain with volume $\int_{\bar D} {dV = 1} $. $\varphi :{\mathbb{R}^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ is ${C^1}$, $\varphi (\infty ) = 0
$ and 
$${\nabla ^2}\varphi  = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}0,x \notin \bar D\\4\pi ,x \in D\end{array} \right.$$
Prove:
$$\int_{\bar D} {\varphi dV \geqslant \frac{-3}{5}} {(\frac{{4\pi }}{3})^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

Comment: This problem came from whether a ball has minimum gravitational potential energy. I tried to do variation like isoperimetric inequality,but have no idea how.